# OpenCV: How to load CHAR data into UCHAR cv::Mat structure from ueye camera

Tags: opencv, char

I have a small problem converting my scripts from IplImage to CvMat structure.
Most scripts I do not have a problem, but in my specific script to capture the image from my ueye camera I can't seem to find a way to get this done without keeping the IplImage in between.

What I would like to do is load the m_pcImageMemory directly into the CvMat structure.. but this is CHAR.. and cv::Mat uses UCHAR.

Does someone has an example how I can create a blank cv::Mat, create the proper header and load the m_pcImageMemory into the new cv::Mat ?

Please see my code below:

```
cv::Mat getframeMat_ueye(){
    if (m_hCam !=0) {
        if (is_CaptureVideo (m_hCam, IS_WAIT) == IS_SUCCESS) {
            is_RenderBitmap (m_hCam, m_lMemoryId, m_hWndDisplay, m_nRenderMode);
        }
    }


    IplImage* tmpImg = cvCreateImageHeader (cvSize (m_nSizeX, m_nSizeY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, m_channels);
    ueye_hasheader=true;
    tmpImg->imageData = m_pcImageMemory; 
    cv::Mat retmat=cv::cvarrToMat(tmpImg);
    cvReleaseImage(&tmpImg);

    return retmat;
}
```

Based on Martin his comments, I changed the code to:

```
cv::Mat getframeMat_ueye(){
    if (m_hCam !=0) {
        if (is_CaptureVideo (m_hCam, IS_WAIT) == IS_SUCCESS) {
            is_RenderBitmap (m_hCam, m_lMemoryId, m_hWndDisplay, m_nRenderMode);
        }
    }

    cv::Mat retmat(m_nSizeX, m_nSizeY,CV_8UC(m_channels),m_pcImageMemory);
    return retmat;
}
```

However, when I do that, the returned image is distored and also the image-size is not correct. (Around have the size in width.)

Greetings and thanks,
Floris.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use iplImage anymore.

cv::Mat mat(sizeX,sizeY,CV_8UC1,the_imagedata_camera);

Obviously the mat is only valid while the data is unchanged. Don't worry about the char/uchar - the data from the camera almost certainyl ISN'T signed!

Comment: Hi @Martin,

As stated above, the sole reason of this post was to get all the IplImage functions out of my code. The only reason it was still in this script was because I can't work around it yet.
I tried changing the code based on your comment, but for some reason the image is distored when I use the this code:

 cv::Mat getframeMat_ueye(){
  if (m_hCam !=0) {
   if (is_CaptureVideo (m_hCam, IS_WAIT) == IS_SUCCESS) {
    is_RenderBitmap (m_hCam, m_lMemoryId, m_hWndDisplay, m_nRenderMode);
   }
  }

  cv::Mat retmat(m_nSizeX, m_nSizeY,CV_8UC(m_channels),m_pcImageMemory);
  return retmat;
 }

Comment: are you sure the data back from the camera is BGR? Check cvtColor() if it isn't